# How to replace model without a prefab file?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to ARCore and followed this article: https://haptic.al/arcore-101-fa6f93d4c003 to add a model with animation and see it with my phone camera.
I switched the model from the article (kitty) with a ball that I downloaded from Unity assets store, I just replaced the previous prefab object with the new one from the ball package that I imported.

Everything works fine, but now I want to download other model from the Unity store and I see that some models don't include the prefabs folder or a prefab file inside the the model package.

Is there another way to switch my current model with a new one without being use the prefab file?

Thank you.

Comment: Having a prefab should not be an issue. You can simply drag & drop the model directly to the field requiring a gameobject. Otherwise, [creating a prefab is very simple](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the downloaded file doesn't contain a prefab you can still create your own prefab by placing the object in the scene (.fbx, .obj files etc.) adding whatever materials you want it to have, and then dragging the name from the Hierarchy panel into the Project panel. The name in the hierarchy panel should turn blue if you've made a prefab successfully.

Note: you don't need a prefab to put something in the scene, a prefab represents an object that has a particular state saved instead of the defaults (transform rotation, materials, colliders, etc.). If you add things to an object and save that object as a prefab then whenever you place that prefab into the scene it will have those components still attached.